# Angular module config - provide parameter for templateURL

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use a parameter in my templateURL. here is relative code:

```
a = angular.module('newmodule', []);
a.config(['$stateProvider',
function ($stateProvider, $rootScope) {
    $stateProvider
        .state('body.new', {
        url: 'new?panelid',
        params: {
            'panelid': function ($rootScope) {
                return $rootScope.panelid;
            }
        },
        templateUrl: function($stateParams){
            return getBaseUrl() + 'newpage.aspx?panel_id='+ $stateParams.panelid;
        },
        controller: 'newController'
    });
}]);
```

The navigation to this state is done like this:

```
var url = $state.href('body.new');
$window.open(url, '_blank');
```

from another state's controller.

I am checking what's been sent to the server and see that $stateParams.panelid is undefined. But, the interesting thing is if instead of returning $rootScope.panelid I return a value like '44' then it works fine. Can someone please explain what's exactly is wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: injecting ` $rootScope` in config phase will throw an error..check console first

Comment: There are no errors. I can even put a break at return $rootScope.panelid; and check its value.

Comment: Oh..I see because in dependency array, you don't have `$rootScope`..

Comment: If how I am trying to do it is not possible, what would a way of providing parameters for templateUrl be?

Comment: Mark the way you are trying is correct..`$stateParams.panelid` should directly return out the value..could you create plunkr of this problem.

Comment: Seems like it would work with transitionTo but not with $window.open.